# Docking multiple QDockWidgets causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qdockwidget

If I have two `QDockWidget`s like so: [image: dockwidgets]

Then calling

```
setFloating(false);
((QMainWindow*) parent())->addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, this);
```

in any of the two dock widgets causes a segmentation fault. What would be a workaround of this problem? I am expecting both widgets to be docked to the `LeftDockWidgetArea` at the same time.

Comment: From the picture it seems that the dock widgets have been already added to the main window dock area, maybe it's not good to add them more times. Maybe, if you want to move them to another area, you have to remove them before with `removeDockWidget`

Comment: Can you generate a backtrace? It would be more helpful to find out what's making your code crash. I suspect `parent()` might be either null or not what you expect it to be. I'd also recommend using `static_cast` instead of a C cast.